# Ag-grid custom filter and server side filter, type is undefined

Tags: angular, ag-grid, ag-grid-angular

According with this website:
[enter link description here](https://www.ag-grid.com/javascript-grid-filter-component/#filter-component)

I build custom filter, but I want to have it as filter server side.
When request is set to the server I have columnName from custom filter, but I don't have type:

```
 function whereSql(request) {
    debugger;
    var whereParts = [];
    var filterModel = request.filterModel;

    if (filterModel) {
      Object.keys(filterModel).forEach(function (key) {
        debugger;
        var item = filterModel[key];
```

In this line  `var item = filterModel[key];` key is undefined, I can see only column name on which my TxtCustomFilter is used. But type is undefined.

[image: server side custom filter empty filter type]

My custom filter looks like:

```
function TxtCustomFilter() {
}

TxtCustomFilter.prototype.init = function (params) {
  this.valueGetter = params.valueGetter;

  this.setupGui(params);
};

// not called by ag-Grid, just for us to help setup
TxtCustomFilter.prototype.setupGui = function (params) {
  this.gui = document.createElement('div');
  this.gui.innerHTML =
    '<div style="padding: 4px; width: 200px;">' +
  //  '<div style="font-weight: bold;">Custom Athlete Filter</div>' +
      '<div><input style="margin: 4px 0px 4px 0px;" type="text" id="filterText" placeholder="Full name search..."/></div>' +
```

...

```
this.filterText = this.gui.querySelector('#filterText');
  this.filterText.addEventListener("changed", listener);
  this.filterText.addEventListener("paste", listener);
  this.filterText.addEventListener("input", listener);

var that = this;

  function listener(event) {
    debugger;
   // that.filterText = event.target.value;
    params.filterChangedCallback();
  }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The interface for filter(inbuilt ones) have below structure

```
// text filter uses this filter model
interface TextFilterModel {
    // always 'text' for text filter
    filterType: string;

    // one of the filter options, e.g. 'equals'
    type: string;

    // the text value associated with the filter.
    // it's optional as custom filters may not
    // have a text value
    filter?: string;
}


// number filter uses this filter model
interface NumberFilterModel {
    // always 'number' for number filter
    filterType: string;

    // one of the filter options, e.g. 'equals'
    type: string;

    // the number value(s) associated with the filter.
    // custom filters can have no values (hence both are optional).
    // range filter has two values (from and to).
    filter?: number;
    filterTo?: number;
}

... same applies to other inbuilt filters.
```

as you can see Ag-Grid defines the `filtertype` as property. which type of filter is rendered is identified by column config provided by the user.

> The `filterType` is not used by the grid when you call `setFilterModel()`. It is provided for information purposes only when you get the filter model. This is useful if you are doing server-side filtering, where the filter type may be used in building back-end queries.

now lets come to your question. you are defining a ***custom filter*** so its your **responsibility** to define the filtertype property on your own as AG-Grid is not involved in custom filter component.

```
TxtCustomFilter.prototype.init = function(params) {
    this.valueGetter = params.valueGetter;
    this.filterText = null;
    this.filterType = 'custom' // define your fitlertype property
    this.setupGui(params);
};
TxtCustomFilter.prototype.getModel = function() {
    return { value: this.filterText.value,
    filtertype : this.filterType };
};
```

Here is a simple [demo](https://plnkr.co/edit/t7VeUVJPGxNX6IW7) which shows how to implement and use it.